# A simple MERGE MySQL query. what is the error in line 1? need assistance

Tags: mysql

```
MERGE emp_old AS T USING emp_new AS S
    ON T.e_id=S.e_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET T.e_age=S.e_age, T.e_salary=S.e_salary
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (e_id,e_name,e_salary, e_age, e_gender, e_dept)
    VALUES(S.e_id,S.e_name,S.e_salary,S.e_age,S.e_gender,S.e_dept)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;
```

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MERGE emp_old AS T USING emp_new AS S  ON T.e_id=S.e_id WHEN MATCHED THEN   UPDA' at line 1

Comment: When did MySQL start supporting MERGE?

Comment: which db you are really using ???

Comment: Where [in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-statements.html) did you find MERGE?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's [there](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/merge-storage-engine.html) of course.. let me just find my glasses and I'll read... Oh